# Entity Framework Core 5 - FROM clause with Include + Skip/Take

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm upgrading my ASP NET Core web application from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 5.0.
I noticed a little difference in how my SQL queries are being generated from LINQ statements when I use Include() and Skip()/Take() together.

I have two tables: **Shops** and **Companies** - Every Shop is assigned to a single Company.
Those are the two table definitions:

```
public class Shop
{
  public int ShopID { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  
  public int CompanyID { get; set; }
  public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
  public int CompanyID { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string VATCode { get; set; }
}
```

... and this is the LINQ expression I am referring to:

```
shopIQ = _context.Shops.Include(x => x.Company)
                       .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
                       .Skip(0).Take(20);
```

With EFCore 2.1 this was translated in this SQL Server query:

```
SELECT [x].[ShopID], [x].[Code], [x].[Name], [x].[CompanyID], [x.Company].[Code] AS [Code0], [x.Company].[Name] AS [Name0], [x.Company].[VATCode] AS [VATCode]
FROM [Shops] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Companies] AS [x.Company] ON [x].[CompanyID] = [x.Company].[CompanyID]
ORDER BY [x].[Code]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

... but with EFCore 5.0 this is translated to:

```
SELECT [t].[ShopID], [t].[Code], [t].[Name], [t].[CompanyID], [c].[CompanyID], [c].[Code], [c].[Name], [c].[VATCode]
FROM (
   SELECT [s].[ShopID], [s].[Code], [s].[Name], [s].[CompanyID]
   FROM [Shops] AS [s]
   ORDER BY [s].[Code]
   OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Companies] AS [c] ON [t].[CompanyID] = [c].[CompanyID]
ORDER BY [t].[Code]
```

which is kinda weird to me.

Anyone knows why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Query looks correct, but really weird. If you need answer - create issue in EF Core repository.

Comment: I have the same issue, any news on this one?

Comment: Having the same issue, searching for some changelog that might mention this. @Svyatoslav can you share the GH issue link?

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho, not a big fan in crawling their issues, you can create new one and they can mark it as duplicate with proper reference.

Comment: The first query would include the navigation property in the skip logic, the second would not. The first could end up not including the company for a shop if the total results exceeded 20, the second query would return 20 shops with the company populated regardless of whether more than 20 rows were returned